# B2B / Wholesale and Product Options Price

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom-options, b2b, customizable-options

I am currently setting up a Magento site that both serves B2B and B2C, everything is absolutely fine as I am using the Advanced Pricing to set our wholesale pricing structures. However I cannot find any way to change the customisation options pricing.

For example, we have product A that retails out at £100, but wholesales for £40, which is absolutely fine. But we offer Gift Wrapping to retail customers for an extra £10, but for wholesale we offer it to them for £4.50 - I cannot find any way to allow anyone on the Wholesale customer group to only pay £4.50 for selecting this product option?

I have also searched through the app store for anything that might be able to resolve this, but have not found anything. The only apps I have found are ones that create a pricing matrix and are very overkill for what we're trying to achieve.

One thing I have considered that I've seen people ask before is to create a Catalogue Price rule or a Customer Group Price Rule, and basically mark everything down by 50% for example, the problem is that the prices we're offering to wholesale isn't a straight "percentage" off, it's a completely different calculated price.

If anyone knows of any apps that could help me out, or any ideas how I could resolve this, it'd be much appreciated.

We're using Magento CE 2 v.2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

For Below;

For example, we have product A that retails out at £100, but wholesales for £40, which is absolutely fine. But we offer Gift Wrapping to retail customers for an extra £10, but for wholesale we offer it to them for £4.50 - I cannot find any way to allow anyone on the Wholesale customer group to only pay £4.50 for selecting this product option?

You will need a custom modules to enable it.

Applying Catalogue price rule will cause an issue when you start using coupon code for each group.